# How to find the core temperature of a mosfet

Tags: powermosfet

I’m designing a step up DC/DC converter and I have to find the core temperature of the MOSFET. The MOSFET is the 2N7000.

I’ve been giving the VDS(ON) and the ambient temperature.

Comment: Read about "thermal resistance". You will construct a series of resistors, each rated in degree Centigrade per Watt; the usual "Ohms" variable has been replaced.

Comment: Bear in mind that a 2N7000 is not really a good choice for a main switching transistor in a dc-dc converter. It may work for low output power, though.

Comment: The data sheet for the part should also provide a junction (or die) to case thermal resistance.  That along with the case to ambient thermal resistance (that varies with how the part is mounted (and heat sunk) should be all you need, given that you have the VDS value and (I assume) the current and duty cycle.

Comment: I guess this is a homework problem. In reality you have to consider switching losses as well as conduction losses.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the die temperature by reverse biasing the substrate diode and measuring its voltage drop. That is how we did it when characterizing them. We placed them in a controlled temperature oil bath and measured the voltage drop using a constant current source after the temperature stabilized. Note the current source can cause heating so use minimal current and leave it off as much as possible. This was done at three different points. This is very hard to do in an active circuit. The characteristics will change from MOSFET batch to batch. The way I see it is to measure the voltage drop from Source to Drain, measure the current then you can calculate the watts. Then using the data sheet you can calculate the die temperature, be sure it is the data sheet for the part you are using, different manufacturers may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the thermal characteristics in he datasheet

[image]

lets assume that ambient temperature is **T0 °C**,

Your power dissipation is **P Watts**,

The temperature of the MOSFET would be given by: **T0 + (R0ja)*P**

i.e **T0 + 357*(P)**

---

If that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The equation that you need is the following:

[image]

Where **Tj** is the junction temperature at the dissipated power **Pd**, **Ta** is the ambient temperature and the **R0ja** is the component's thermal resistance between the junction and the ambient.
In your application, you know which is the power that your Mosfet will dissipate, because it's: [image: Dissipated power],  you know the thermal resistance because it's given in the datasheet, and you can foresee the ambient temperature around your board (eg. 30°C if your board is laying in an open space, 45°C if it is enclosed in a box with other warm component etc.)

[image]

this being said, you can easily calculate the junction temperature and compare it with the maximum Tj specified in the datasheet, which in your case is 150°C max. (but remember that operating at the maximum specs it' highly not recommended)

Comment: The power you computed should be derated by the worst case duty cycle.  The MOSFET is not going to be on 100% of the time.